# noise calculation for LM741

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, spice

my circuit is very simple, i want to calculation output when i apply 0 amplitude sine-wave to do circuit
[image]

from datasheet,

```
LM741
input offset current 20nA,
offset voltage       1mV,
```

when i do math , 27mV + 20nA * 52k = 28.04 mV but i see 32.292899mV at spice graph.
There are some parameters which i dont know , but i checked something like what happens if i try delete **dc offset (with capacitor coupling)** result is **6.2968517mV** at this time.

also i checked try to minimize **input offset current** like **add resistor** Vsinus between non-inverting input , (same value as R21 **52k**),

result is

[image]

there are 3.2878795mV voltage which i cant explain what it is when i coupled capacitor and added resistor Vsinus between Non-Inverting input?

Why am i getting result like that ? i'm tried to zero output if i applied 0 to input. What can cause it like that ? Resistor error ? or another else.. ?
Thank you

Comment: You do realize you are looking at nanovolts in the graph, right? Also the values in datasheets are not accurate to 7 decimals. 28mV vs. 32mV in this application is what we call "close enough".

Comment: It's very difficult to guess what the question could be. Maybe you can describe what you would like to see and what the actual result is.

Comment: @Mario i editted my question

Comment: @jippie as you see this isnt real oscilloscope , it just a spice output , the program reaches this conclusion by calculating something and what can it be ?

Comment: Don't trust SPICE models on offset voltage or current. That 1 mV Vos might sometimes be +1 mV and sometimes -1 mV. The model might just take the "typical" value to be 0. Offset currents are more likely to be biased one way or the other, but still there can be a lot of part-to-part variation so the SPICE model isn't going to represent any particular part you take off the reel. If this kind of offset is an issue in your application, choose a better op-amp.

Comment: @ThePhoton of course you are right , in my application i will choose zero drift op amp but just i'm trying to learn these , i'm starting from basic op amp and practicing offset voltage or current or noise density calculation. and i want ,my calculation result and simulation programs result are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question's title is "Noise calculation" yet you simulate using a transient simulation. I hope that you're aware that you **cannot simulate noise in a transient simulation** at least not in Pspice/Ltspice as far as I know. (Cadence Spectre can do transient noise but let's stay on topic).

You also seem to want to determine DC offset, for that I would use a DC operating point simulation. But beware that this offset simulation does not relate much to reality. In reality the offset is different for each opamp. To do a really proper offset analysis you must use DC analysis in combination with Monte Carlo analysis and a statistical model of the opamp (not all models have statistical data included).

You're using a transient simulation which is intended for simulations with time-varying signals. You're suprised that the output gives a constant 3.2mV which is what can be expected in the simulation you setup.

A DC simulation will give you a more accurate offset simulation as it will eliminate all time varying properties that are present in the opamp's model.

For noise analysis you must use the noise simulation, there is no other way.

Comment: what can i say you are right ...
i do DC analysis and result is 3.28788mV , almost the same , but i figured out something when i decrease resistors in my circuit result decrease also. is it maybe relevant resistor ?

Comment: Instead of asking is this OK, is that OK ? Try to find an explanation yourself. **How** does the simulator calculate the offset. In your calculation you assume the 20 nA is flowing through the 52 k resistor. Why not (partly) through the 2 k resistor ?

Comment: in my knowledge , if it is wrong correct me please ,input bias current flow feedback resistor and enter to the input op amp , 2k resistor isnt include that path.

Comment: Why not ? + input of opamp is 0 V, offset is +1 mV so - input of opamp is -1 mV. So there's 1 mV across R22 1mV/2.2k = 454nA flowing through R22.

Comment: Yeah you are right , i'm desperate now. i'll check my circuit again

Comment: If you have not read it yet, I highly recommend "Opamps for everyone", a free download at: http://www.cypress.com/file/65366/download  It shows how to do calculations on offset for several opamp circuits.